# Trying to create a virtual keyboard in flash that inputs text into whatever text field is selected

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create a virtual keyboard for a touchscreen app I am working on. I have more than one text field and I would like the keyboard to be able enter characters in whatever text field I am currently in.

Currently most of the examples online allow me to enter characters in a specific textfield with the: textfield.text = ""

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not clear: are you trying to use device-specific soft keyboard, or creating UI of your own.

Comment: My own. It isn't going to be on a device. It will be run from a laptop as an air app. And the laptop will be output to a custom touch screen. The touch screen doesn't have a keyboard. I would like to make my own in the app.

Comment: Hmmm, a tricky one. You might want to listen to **FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN** and **FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT** (or maybe just **MouseEvent.CLICK**) to track which one of the input fields were selected. Then, use **TextField.selectionBeginIndex** and **TextField.selectionEndIndex**, or maybe just **TextField.replaceSelectedText(...)** to emulate user input: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#replaceSelectedText()

Answer (score 1):

as this?

```
   var tempTextField:TextField;
   textsContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, textContainerHandler);
   private function textContainerHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
   if(event.target != event.currentTarget)
      tempTextField = event.target as TextField;
   }

   private function virtualKeyboardHandler(key:String):void
   {
     tempTextField.appendText(key);
   }
```

Comment: Backspace case? Select text to replace/delete case?

Comment: backsapce its eazy.
about select text - 
       if(textField.selectionBeginIndex == textField.caretIndex)
           replaceSelectedText(key);

check http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html there are all

Comment: Did you check if mouse *down then drag* gesture to select a part of text produces **CLICK** as well? What I am saying is that your answer does not seem to be a complete solution that covers all the possible cases, thus I encourage you to improve the answer's quality. It is already good that you are willing to help, just be thorough with it. Otherwise OP (and other people looking for the same thing) might end up with a bugged solution which might be worse than no solution at all.